# Android application with switch statement crashes on my phone

Tags: java, android, xml

When I run this code on my Android Phone, it keeps on crashing.

My java code is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
String string = edit.getText().toString();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (string){
                case "c":
                    MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sample1);
                    mp1.start();
                    break;
```

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="pembroke.com.example.algorhythmic.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="308dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.781" />
```

The code is crashing, but I don't know why. I might not be using the string correctly.

No errors in the code but it is still crashing. Is it because the Android IDE can't compute my code?

Comment: please connect the phone to the pc, make it crash again and post here the error msg you get

Comment: It says: Unfortunately Algorhythmic has stopped. There is no error message in android studio.

Comment: the error in the IDE not in the phone please!

Comment: First of all post all your code not parts of it. Second you can't `findViewById` before you `setContentView` so you're definitelly getting nullpointerexception when setting the buttons click listener.

Comment: yet another `findViewById` before `setContentView` please learn some android's basics

Comment: @Selvin  its crashing still. I switched the declaration of the id after the setcontentview but it still doesnt work. What now? and, that is all the code I have.

Comment: @nbokmans not working :( I tried declaring it after but its still crashing my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 problems with the code :

1. For doing the findViewById, we do this after setContentView in onCreate method of activity. This is because, before setContentView, all views are null. Hence, I moved the findViewById code for both EditText and button after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) in onCreate method of activity.
2. For the edittext, the ID which you used is R.id.text in java code, but in xml, it is R.id.box. So I have changed that to R.id.box in java code when doing the findViewById.
3. To find the value present in EditText, we have to get text present in EditText inside the onClickListener since the value inside EditText keeps on changing as user enters inside EditText.
   Hence we assign the value to variable string inside the onClickListener's onClick method.

So final code would be :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText edit;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edit  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.box);
        button  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String string = edit.getText().toString();
                switch (string){
                    case "c":
                        MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sample1);
                        mp1.start();
                        break;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @DavidDoyle. Can you please upvote the answer and also accept it. Thanks